# JQuery Mobile form submission getElementById for current new form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form that will open a new form after submission, while showing the results of previous form submission. I need to get the element value from new form using `getElementById().value`. However, it always return old data element from old form.

eg:

- before any navigation, I will have only one line of barbar value, which cause no problem for `getElementById().value`.

`<input type="text" value="1" id="barbar" autofocus="">`

- After form submission and redirected to the same page with the same form, I got 2 line of the data with different value. One is from the previous data and one is the current updated one. `getElementById().value` only return me the first line value.

`<input type="text" value="1" id="barbar" autofocus="">`

`<input type="text" value="3" id="barbar" autofocus="">`

How to access the second element value. Why data from previous form will still appear at the new form or next page? Please correct me if I am wrong and would like to listen to any guidance or practice.

The codes were simplified as this:

```
// html
<form action="<?=Yii::app()->createUrl('mobile/container/test');?>" method="post">
<input type="text" data-type="search" value="" name="barbar" id="barbar" autofocus>
</form>

// controller action
public function actionTest()
    {
       if(isset($_POST['barbar']))
        {
            $this->render('unload',array(
             'barbar'=>$_POST['barbar']
             )));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->render('unload'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do u mean by 'Redirecting to same form'? u are appending the same form again, or how is it, can u share some code as well?

Comment: Elements must have unique id within the document, use a class to identify the inputs.

Comment: @Teemu I want to built a scanning function which will keep redirecting me to this form while showing the result of previous submitted form. Isit means I need to dynamically assign a new id each time a form is submitted?

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh Sorry for making an unclear question. I have edited the question and share some codes. Please have a view :)

Comment: use classes in that case, otherwise it will become messy, then getElemenetsByClassName will give an array, u can use the elements as required.

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh Noted with thanks! Do you know what causes the data from previous form appear at the new form? I only know it may due to jquery mobile nature and was trying to study more about it but failed to get the right term for me to google about.

Comment: It's not jQuery, it's your PHP creating the response. When taking a look at the PHP code you have, the logic seems to be broken. You're responsing with `render('unload')` if `barbar` exists, and also responsing with `render('unload')` if `barbar` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Teemu Sorry for the confusion. I have simplified the codes and in my code there is a difference between these 2 conditions. I have changed the code in my question. I wonder why there is always cache the first page html elements even after I directed to the next page. Unless I make a refresh on that page, then only the cache html elements of the first page link will be cleared. Do you have any ideas on what i should looks for?

Comment: Now, after the edit, that totally depends on what `render` method does. We need to see that function to answer the question (and maybe some other code from the class). I'd suggest you to ask a new question with PHP and possible other relevant tags, and not to edit this question any further. Show the code, and explain in details what is happening, and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you for reading my questions. Fyi, the code written above are giving me the same issue as my full codes. I will take note on your advice for my further question.